# Weird spacing at bottom of boxes in Pure CSS Masonry layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with Pure CSS Mansonry layout. I use `position: relative` for the boxes and `position: absolute` for the content inside each box. However, I noticed that when I use `position: absolute`, there's an gap under each box. I couldn't figure out how to fix it. You can also check it out at this codepen: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/KWjXeG

HTML

```css
@import "compass/css3";

*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.servicogallery {
 -moz-column-gap: 0;
 -webkit-column-gap: 0; 
  -moz-column-count: 3;-webkit-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#services {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:  0;
 padding:  1rem;
 width:  100%; 
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
#services span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #0026e7;
  color: #FFF;
}
.a2 {
  background-color:/*#189ed8*/#ffffff;
    color: /*#FFF*/#998b75;
}
.a3 {    
  background-color:/*#fff*/#bac0b8;
    color: /*#998b75*/#ffffff;
}
.a4 {    background-color: #646664;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a5 {background-color: #0026e7;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a6 {background-color: #29a1e6;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a7 {background-color: #fff;
    color: #998b75;
}
.a8 {background-color: #bac0b8;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a9 {    background-color: #fff;
    color: #998b75;
}
.a10 {    background-color: #0029e5;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a11 {    background-color: #5e605e;
    color: #FFF;
}

/*  styles for background color, etc; not necessary for this thing to work  */



body {
 padding:  1em;
 font-family:  "Garamond", serif; 
}




h1 {
  font-size:  3rem;
  font-weight:  800;
}

body {
  line-height:  1.25;
}


p {
 text-align:  left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Masonry</h1>
<p>By using CSS3 columns, we can easily create a Masonry.js-like layout where random-height blocks fit together.</p>

<div class="servicogallery">

  <div id="services" class="a1">
    <span>
      <p>Formulación y Evaluación  de Proyectos de Construcción.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a2">
    <span>
      <p>Mantenimiento Varios (Edificaciones, Calles, entre otros).</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a3">
    <span>
      <p>Diseño: Arquitectónico, Habitacional, Industrial, Urbano y Comercial.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a4">
    <span>
      <p>Taludes, Muros.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a5">
    <span>
      <p>Supervisión de Proyectos</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a6">
    <span>
      <p>Estudios de Factibilidad  Técnica – Económica de proyectos de construcción.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a7">
    <span>
      <p>Diseño Integral de Obras  de Ingeniería y Arquitectura.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a8">
    <span>
      <p>Tramitología.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a9">
    <span>
      <p>Obras de Mitigación</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a10">
    <span>
      <p><strong>Construcción de Obras Civiles  y Remodelaciones:</strong></p>
      <p>Centros comerciales, urbanizaciones, infraestructura: Hidráulica y Víal, complejos industriales, turísticos, deportivo, centros decapacitación, vivienda, centros educativo, hospitales, taludes, muros, obras de mitigación</p>
      <p>Aplicación de pintura con maquinaria industrial avanzada, entre otros.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="services" class="a11">
    <span>
      <p>Uso de equipo para la realización de pruebas no destructivas en concreto.</p></span>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is no gaps around the boxes as well the content to be at bottom of each box. All I could tell is that the `position: absolute` is affecting the gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `#services`

```css
@import "compass/css3";

*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.servicogallery {
 -moz-column-gap: 0;
 -webkit-column-gap: 0; 
  -moz-column-count: 3;-webkit-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#services {
 margin:  0;
 padding:  1rem;
 width:  100%; 
 height: 250px;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
}
#services span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #0026e7;
  color: #FFF;
}
.a2 {
  background-color:/*#189ed8*/#ffffff;
    color: /*#FFF*/#998b75;
}
.a3 {    
  background-color:/*#fff*/#bac0b8;
    color: /*#998b75*/#ffffff;
}
.a4 {    background-color: #646664;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a5 {background-color: #0026e7;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a6 {background-color: #29a1e6;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a7 {background-color: #fff;
    color: #998b75;
}
.a8 {background-color: #bac0b8;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a9 {    background-color: #fff;
    color: #998b75;
}
.a10 {    background-color: #0029e5;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a11 {    background-color: #5e605e;
    color: #FFF;
}

/*  styles for background color, etc; not necessary for this thing to work  */



body {
 padding:  1em;
 font-family:  "Garamond", serif; 
}




h1 {
  font-size:  3rem;
  font-weight:  800;
}

body {
  line-height:  1.25;
}


p {
 text-align:  left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS Masonry</h1>
<p>By using CSS3 columns, we can easily create a Masonry.js-like layout where random-height blocks fit together.</p>

<div class="servicogallery">

  <div id="services" class="a1">
    <span>
      <p>Formulación y Evaluación  de Proyectos de Construcción.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a2">
    <span>
      <p>Mantenimiento Varios (Edificaciones, Calles, entre otros).</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a3">
    <span>
      <p>Diseño: Arquitectónico, Habitacional, Industrial, Urbano y Comercial.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a4">
    <span>
      <p>Taludes, Muros.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a5">
    <span>
      <p>Supervisión de Proyectos</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a6">
    <span>
      <p>Estudios de Factibilidad  Técnica – Económica de proyectos de construcción.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a7">
    <span>
      <p>Diseño Integral de Obras  de Ingeniería y Arquitectura.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a8">
    <span>
      <p>Tramitología.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a9">
    <span>
      <p>Obras de Mitigación</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a10">
    <span>
      <p><strong>Construcción de Obras Civiles  y Remodelaciones:</strong></p>
      <p>Centros comerciales, urbanizaciones, infraestructura: Hidráulica y Víal, complejos industriales, turísticos, deportivo, centros decapacitación, vivienda, centros educativo, hospitales, taludes, muros, obras de mitigación</p>
      <p>Aplicación de pintura con maquinaria industrial avanzada, entre otros.</p></span>
  </div>

  <div id="services" class="a11">
    <span>
      <p>Uso de equipo para la realización de pruebas no destructivas en concreto.</p></span>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Yes it'll work. However, when I use it on my actual web page, the height is somehow not working.

Comment: @KristinaBressler can you link to your website? can't help you if I can't see it. You might try adding `!important` to the height?

Comment: It's a wordpress site and you cannot see it because it'll only show the message "Under construction website coming soon". You'll have to log in to the wordpress website to be able to see the actual page...

Comment: @KristinaBressler bummer. it's up to you to reproduce the problem on Stack Overflow for us, otherwise all I can do is guess at what the issue is and that isn't productive for either of us.

Comment: If I create a user with the role "subscriber", will you be able to take a look??

Comment: @KristinaBressler sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140207/discussion-between-kristina-bressler-and-michael-coker).

Comment: Please email me when you come back because I'm still having problems

Comment: @KristinaBressler can you not add the relevant code to your post on stack overflow?

Comment: I just finished adding the rest of the code to the codepen. You can now fiddle around in the codepen. I also updated the snippet too

Comment: @KristinaBressler http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/MpMQMd you're saying the boxes don't have a height now?

Comment: it doesn't have a height when I use display: block. Pure CSS Masonry only works if I use display: inline-block.

Comment: @KristinaBressler seems to work fine with an `inline-flex` and `column` display http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/MpMQMd

Comment: @KristinaBressler updated my answer, `vertical-align: top` will remove the gap with `display: inline-block`